# What are the evidences from scriptures behind Radha-Krishna getting (or not getting) married?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, marriage, radha

I remember there was a scene in the movie Prem Rog (1982), where Rishi Kapoor is standing in front of a Radha-Krishna temple and people are asking him what is his relationship with the female protagonist? They gave him two choices, brother or husband. To which he asks all of them, is that the only relationship that can exists between a young man-woman. Everyone agrees. To which Rishi Kapoor simply asks, what was the relationship between these (pointing towards the Radha-Krishna idol inside the temple)? Were they brother-sisters or husband-wife? After that, no surprises, he got beaten up by the crowd. But that scene inspired me greatly. That scene showed me that religion (at least Hinduism) is not regressive. It is the people who interpret it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sq7PtckKgyI) is the complete scene in Hindi.

But recently I have heard that there are some evidence in the literature which states that Radha-Krishna were indeed married in secret in presence of Brahma ji. In fact Brahma ji officiated their wedding.

But such claims are based on only two scriptures: Garg Samhita ([source](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36665/9341)) and Brahmavaivarta Purana. [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31808/9341) answer states that story of Radha is not detailed in scriptures other than Brahmavaivarta Purana. [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11063/9341) answer states that only Gaudiya Vaishnavas follow Garg Samhita. However, [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19024/9341) answer claims that Radha-Krishna were not married.

It is not that Radha is not mentioned in other scriptures. She is mentioned in [Shiv Mahapuran](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20496/9341), [Padma Puraan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/55814/9341), and [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radha#Literature_and_symbolism).

So my question is, what are some other evidences from scriptures on this topic? i.e. marriage of Radha with Krishna or anyone else.

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/did-brahma-solemnize-marriage-of-krishna-and-radha) is a similar question to mine (with less motivation) but sadly nobody has answered it.

Comment: K.M munshi's Krishnavatara is just a fictional novel. That is not a source about Radha's life. I don't know why anybody will quote that as an answer.

Comment: questions about cinema plots are best directed to the writers of those cinemas. they have nothing to do with religion.